# after upgrade to 16.04 got stuck with low resolution, no hdmi, unity slow as hell (Radeon HD 7500G, Samsung NP535U3C))

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, hdmi, display-resolution

Just like in the topic: after upgrading from 15.10 (?) to 16.04 everything related to display/video card is completely f***ed up.

1.

lspci:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7500G]
```

and xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*
```

after

```
cvt 1366 768 60 

xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode default 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output default --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

I got:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

although xrandr now shows:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
 1024x768      76.00* 
 1368x768_60.00  59.88
```

2.

HDMI - just doesn't react in any way on connecting external display

3.

Damn slow, no acceleration, unity is eating CPU, had to switch to lxde - but it's no fun. Especially with sh**ty resolution.